# Cloud Firestore is not adding data in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In my project, I simply created a form with an image picker. The idea is to create an event data with name, email, image and more. I already uploaded the image to Firebase storage but I cannot add the rest of my data to Firestore.

The data is correctly fetched and passed to next page, though.

Here is my code:

```
  onPressed: () async {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()&& _image!=null){
      var name = nameController.text;
      var price = priceController.text;
      var description = descriptionController.text;
      var location = locationController.text;
      var ticket = ticketController.text;
      var date;
      if(dateChecked==true){
        setState(() {
          date = _startDate;
        });
      }
      else if(dateChecked==false){
        setState(() {
          date=_days[_selectedDay];
        });
      }
      var time = _time;
      var type = _options[_selectedIndex];
      var img;
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
       Reference reference = await _storage.ref().child('${name}/${date}');
       final UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image);
       uploadTask.whenComplete(() async{
         img = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
         print(img);
         Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => PostSuccess(
                 name,price,date,time,location,type,_image,description,ticket
             )));
       });
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').doc(name).set(
          {
            'name': name,
            'price': price,
            'date': date,
            'time': time,
            'location': location,
            'type': type,
            'description': description,
            'tickets': ticket
          });
    }
    else{
      print('validate first');
    }
  },
```

Where am I making the mistakes?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This ...
if this didn't work then let me know

```
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').doc(name).set(
                                  {
                                    'name': name,
                                    'price': price,
                                    'date': date,
                                    'time': time,
                                    'location': location,
                                    'type': type,
                                    'description': description,
                                    'tickets': ticket
                                  },).then((value){});
```

Comment: and now it add those data to firestore. but when I added imgURL it displays null. i tried to convert it to string but no change. `'imgURL': img.toString()`